# Dynamically add image to web page head using Javascript - will browser fetch image?

Tags: javascript, browser, dynamic

If I were to dynamically add an image to a web page from JavaScript, and I add that image to the <head> section, then if I set the image src property, will the browser fetch that image for me or will it not bother because as it doesn't display images from the <head> section in the rendered page, there is no point fetching it?

On IE8, it still fetched it, but I'm wondering if I can rely on that behavior on all browsers?

Comment: yes you load dynamically load image through ajax and all browsers render it...a simple example of it is when you click on home in facebook the middle part i.e the feeds gets loaded..

Comment: in my original post, the <head> word was stripped out for some reason.

Comment: Why do you wanna put it in the <head> section?

Comment: @jishi I'd prefer not to. I am going to look for a script element as the place to add the image as I can rely on there being at least one on the page. I cannot add to BODY using document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(my_img) because of a bug in IE6 (and unpatched IE7/8) which means you cannot append to the BODY element from script that isn't a direct child to the BODY element.

Comment: How about a container with display: none to which you append your images?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could know is through testing. It should be pretty easy to test with a large image, a collection of browsers, and a network bandwidth monitor.

Even if you can find that most major browser do this, I still wouldn't rely on it.

Why would you want to?